# Execute method from string

Tags: java, string

I have a String that contains method names with arguments.I wanna execute all methods.How can I do that.Consider following input -

```
String s="second(first(\"string1\"))";
```

where `first(String s)` and `second(String s)` are two method in my class.

Note that when I change `Strings s=second(first("string1"));` manually,its working fine, I'm looking for some dynamic approach to do same.

(If possible then without reflection).

Comment: Google "Java Reflection API".

Comment: And for the record: there are some reasonable use cases for reflection. But unless you fall into that rare category ... bad idea. Rather step back and look at the problem you really have to solve, and look for ways to do that differently.

Comment: @GhostCat I've updated my question , please check again.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I've updated my question , please check again.

Comment: You could use a dynamic language such as Groovy instead of Java.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Thanks for suggestion , but groovy is not an option here. We need to do that using JAVA only.

Comment: @GhostCat please remove duplicate mark from question.

Comment: I added another existing question that discusses "dynamic" compiling. Your question is really not at all new - do some research first!

Comment: Here is the implementation using `janino-compiler` : https://www.jdoodle.com/a/tmn